# jQuery UI Autocomplete - setting source after _create/_init not working?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

According to the jQuery UI, you should set the autocomplete source after create/init as follows:

$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "source", ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"] );

Here is some of the code (based off of the [combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html)  example):

```
     $("#item").combobox();
     $("#item").autocomplete("option", "source", function (request, response) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "itmsrch.ashx",
             dataType: "json",
             data: {
                 dept: $("#dept").val,
                 term: request.term
             },
             success: function (data) {
                 response($.map(data, function (item) {
                     return {
                         label: item.name,
                         value: item.name
                     }
                 }));
             }
         });
     });
```

After typing the required 2 characters to kick off the autocomplete action, I am getting an error that the source is not set.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this won't work is that the combobox sample actually creates an input and applies the `autocomplete` widget to *it* and not the `select` that you called `combobox()` on:

```
/* Snip */
var input = this.input = $( "<input>" )
    .insertAfter( select )
    .val( value )
    .autocomplete({ ... });
/* Snip */
```

In order to modify the source of combobox's internal autocomplete, you could write:

```
$("#combobox").next("input").autocomplete("option", "source", ["Foo", "Bar"]);
```

Or, more generally, you could add the following to the plugin:

```
_setOption: function(key, value) {
    this.input.data("autocomplete")._setOption(key, value);
}
```

And then modify autocomplete options using:

```
$("#item").combobox("option", "source", ["Foo", "Bar"]);
```

I'd recommend this method.

However, this will cause issues because the combobox code's event handler for the autocomplete's `select` expects that the selected item has an `option` property (check out the source code).  Additionally, this will break any event handlers you have on the `select` (e.g. `change`).

If you don't care about updating the underlying select (which I bet you don't since you're changing the datasource), you can remove the `select` event handler *entirely*.

I have a working example ***[here](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/Z4uRU/)*** that uses the last method and seems to work okay.